# See live changes when editing code across multiple dependent projects in a VS Code Workspace

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-workspace

I am developing a Python application (`app`), which relies on an internal Python library (`lib`) that is developed as a separate project. The main application depends on the library via a Git reference (`pip install -e git+https://…` or equivalent for Poetry). Both `app` and `lib` are developed in parallel by the same team.

I am using a [multi-root workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces) in VS Code for development, and I have created a parent folder in which both projects are checked out in subfolders, and with a `product.code-workspace` definition file as follows:

```json
{
    "folders": [
        { "path": "app" },
        { "path": "lib" }
    ]
}
```

`lib` contains a single file `lib/__init__.py`:

```py
def hello() -> str:
    return "hello world"
```

`app` contains the following `app/__init__.py`:

```py
import lib


def main():
    print(lib.hello())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Both projects are set up in their own virtual environment.

**When debugging `app`, how can I tell VS Code to load the *actual*, live code from the `lib` subfolder rather than the dependency installed in the virtual environment of `app`?**

In other words, if I change the `lib/__init__.py` file above to:

```py
def hello() -> str:
    return "goodbye"
```

And run `app` in VS Code, how do I get it to print the output `goodbye` instead of `hello world` *without* having to commit & push the code changes in `lib` and reinstalling the dependency in `app`?

A workaround is to set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable in `app`’s `launch.json` configuration (`"${workspaceFolder}/../lib"`). However, I cannot use this because I have *multiple* project dependencies (`lib1`, `lib2`, …) so I would have to assign multiple directories to `PYTHONPATH`. But unfortunately the syntax for this differs across platform (Windows uses `;` as path separator, whereas Linux and macOS use `:`), and I would prefer having a cross-platform launch configuration that can be fully committed to version control.

I know that you can have joint launch configurations in the workspace (and in fact I am using them!) but I couldn’t find an option here to specify that VS Code should use “live”, local dependencies rather than installed dependencies when launching the application.

---

For completeness, I have uploaded an MCVE for the two projects to GitHub. To set it up, run:

```bash
mkdir test-app && cd $_
git clone git@github.com:klmr/py-test-app app
git clone git@github.com:klmr/py-test-lib lib

cd app
python3 -m venv .venv
.venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Next, add the `product.code-workspace` configuration from above to the main folder, and launch it in VS Code. Now navigate to `lib/lib/__init__.py`, edit the function `hello` to return a different value, and save.

Launch `app` via <kbd>F5</kbd>. It prints `hello world`, not the changed value.

Comment: I should add that I cannot combine the projects into a single repository, since the `lib`s are also used by various other projects, all of which are large applications with complex deployment logic.

Answer (score 1):

> But unfortunately the syntax for this differs across platform (Windows uses `;` as path separator, whereas Linux and macOS use `:`

Pretty sure you can just do this in your launch config:

```json
"windows": {
    "env": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "foo;bar",
    },
},
"osx": {
    "env": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "foo:bar",
    },
},
"linux": {
    "env": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "foo:bar",
    },
},
```

Note that if you use the play button at the top right, that doesn't use launch configs and you need to use the `terminal.integrated.env.<platform>` VS Code settings instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably missing something here, because your question sounds like its more complicated than this, but... install the actual `lib` working copy as editable for the `app`'s interpreter or venv, i.e.

```
pip install -e wherever/youve/put/lib
```

(Then, forget about `lib`'s venv, it doesn't matter (aside from maybe running tests in `lib`'s directory).)

The requirements in your MCVE have an editable requirement pointing to Github, which means Pip will clone the repo into a temporary directory, so that doesn't reflect your actual situation.

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t see a way of doing this without making either local setup or CI/CD drastically more complicated. As in, I’d rather not have to set up dependencies manually, which this seems to need. The setup should be as simple as `poetry install` (or, in the case of my MCVE, `pip install -r requirements.txt`). Maybe I could use `requirements-dev.txt`?

Comment: You can have an `-e ../lib` requirement in a requirements txt file...

Comment: In any case, I use `pip install -e ../some-inhouse-lib` heavily so I can develop a feature in `app` against a "future" version of `some-inhouse-lib`, and when everything's done and dusted, and a new version of `some-inhouse-lib` is published (or tagged), the actual (pinned) requirements in `app` are changed to point towards that new version of `some-inhouse-lib` and sent off to PR/CI land.